# Unable to install Hyperledger Fabric Marbles chaincode from a repository to a peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm using this Hyperledger Fabric [tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/private_data_tutorial.html#pd-build-json), I am block on the step 1 of part **Install chaincode on all peers**
When I run the command `peer chaincode install -n marblesp -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/marbles02_private/go/`I have the following result containing an error :

```
2018-12-10 13:19:37.515 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2018-12-10 13:19:37.515 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: Error getting chaincode code chaincode: path to chaincode does not exist: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/fabric-samples/chaincode/marbles02_private
```

Could you help me please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the chaincodes in this path? Be sure you have the chaincode in this path.

Do you have Go installed? If yes, do you export the Go path?

Try with this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```